Request for Advice on Motivation Letter
As an international student, must I acknowledge a country's culture in my motivation letter (for an Engineering course)

Is this letter for a degree application? "Course" means different things in different places. The tag you have used has a different meaning also. It isn't about such letters.

Is there a reason you think acknowledging a country’s culture would be beneficial? In what way?

It's unclear to me what you are asking. But if your question is: "if I want to study in the US (for example), do I need to talk about US culture or about my country's culture in my motivation letter?" then the answer is: definitely not.

There is no reason that you "must" do that. If that culture is something that does, indeed, motivate you then you can, of course, but it isn't necessary.
Why do you want to study in the field you have chosen? What motivates you for a career in that field? Are you motivated to teach? To do research? Focus on those things. But family, culture, even religion, could be motivating for some people. Likewise a desire to contribute to the future of one's country or culture can be a positive motivation.

Thank you, this answers my question. I appreciate everyone's contributions
